# Why my $emit and $broadcast example not working?

Tags: angularjs

Example :

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent" class="ng-scope">
  { { parent.data } }
  <div ng-controller="SiblingOneCtrl as sib1" class="ng-scope">
      { { sib1.data } }
  </div>
</div>


 <script>
function ParentCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data'); // идет вниз!

}
function SiblingOneCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // ‘Some data’
  });
}
 </script>
```

Download a sample on this forum and people write it working

opening the console, I have not seen any effects 
Waiting tips ..thank you indifferent people

Comment: Could be because its firing before sibling is initialized. Try it with with $timeout in parentctrl.

Comment: try to put your scripts in `$(document).ready` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happens most likely because it fires the broadcast before that listener in sibling is even created.

a) don't broadcast immediately, using delay(`$timeout`) for example..

b) or pass the data some other way, using prototype inheritance or even a service(you set in on parent and get it in sibling)

c) you most likely want to broadcast something on ng-click or something anyway, don't you? in which case it should work just fine as it is.

Answer (score 4):

foxx told right Try it with with $timeout in parentctrl as :

```
function ParentCtrl ($scope,$timeout) {
this.data="r";
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data'); // идет вниз!
},1000)


}
function SiblingOneCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // ‘Some data’
  });
}
```

[see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8FyDb7TIhhbOCc8xtMG?p=preview) for working code

Comment: no need of 1000 delay in $timeout, even 0 millisecond would work